# Google App Engine - Saving User Records Quickly to Datastore, Transactions, Entity Groups

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, entity-group-transactions, nosql

We have thousands of users, each with 1000 records. Both users and records are represented by models in our application.

Saving 1000 records individually per user takes ages (30+ seconds). However, considering all of these records belong to the same user, can be save them all in one go?

As I understand it, using Entity Groups, it could be all done in one transaction, but can't find any clear documentation on how to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: and you want that because you are running out of the hard limit of 30 seconds per request? or you just wanted to speed up the whole thing?

Comment: Just do it with TaskQueue.

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi We're looking at Tasks, but it just fundamentally doesn't seem to make sense for, say, 300KB of data to take 30 seconds to save, and then use Tasks as a workaround instead of solving the original problem (slow saves). It can be done on SQL box in a fraction of a second. Is this a NoSQL limitation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transactions do not make processing faster. If anything, they are slower.

You can speed up processing by saving entities in [batches](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Batch_operations) (up to 1,000 entities per call).

Comment: Is there an equivalent for NDB? I've tried multi_put, which is still slow.

Comment: Use .put_async(), your app wont have to wait for the put to finish. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#using

Comment: @Bruyere are there any limitations to this approach other than not being around to retrieve a result?

Comment: Not that I've found so far. Seeing as the data takes time even after the normal put has gone through you wont actually see any difference in the time it takes to become available.

Comment: Thanks @Bruyere, insight appreciated.